# .NET Core - How to redirect to identity server sign in from a controller using Identity Server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add a "silent" external authentication provider to our authentication server (Identity Server).

This basically means a button can be placed on one of our suppliers websites that'll log them straight into our application, but we can't go from supplier site -> Identity Server as it seems that this is not supported, only our login page -> post to Identity Server.

My current thought process is to create a custom controller on the main application that would have the provider name passed to it from our supplier site. Then that can redirect the request to the authentication server but with an extra parameter that I can detect and use to push the user into the correct external authentication work flow. Has anyone out there done this before and found a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. you want to use your suppliers authentication server as external authentication for your IDP/Authentication server?

Comment: @Kevin exactly that!

Comment: I'll try write up an answer that will hopefully be helpful (it might take a couple of hours or be early tomorrow though). I believe what you are doing should be possible